# Upload File and Convert to Base64 (406 Error Not Acceptable )

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, http-headers, httpwebrequest

What I am trying to do here is that I am going to send a converted pdf to base64 to an endpoint where in this is the endpoint

```
HTTP-HEADERS:

api-key: your-key

Content-Type: application/json

 

Request Body JSON

{

"file": 
      {
        "mime": "application/pdf",

        "data": "base64-data="
       }
}
```

and here's how I Upload and Convert the my file

```
 public async Task UploadFile()
        {
            
            FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
            if (fileData == null)
                return; //user canceled selecting image

            string fileName = fileData.FileName;
            string contents = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData.DataArray);
            var stream = fileData.GetStream();
            var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

            File ru = new File();
            ru.mime = "application/pdf";
            ru.data = "base64-data="+base64;


string url = "ENDPOINT URL";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                .Accept
                .Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ru);
            HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            requestMessage.Headers.Add("api-key", "API KEY HERE");
            requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if(result!= null)
            {
                resultLabel = result;
            }
```

now it gives me the error

> {"Message":"HTTP 406 Not Acceptable. There was an error with your request. Please check your payload and then try again,","Result":406}

Comment: A MIME attachment is after the closing body tag and starts with two dashes.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)

Comment: in a previous question you noted that this worked using Postman - Postman should be able to generate C# for you that you can use in your app.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Jason I did not know this how???

Comment: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: Hmmm a restsharp . Alright I will try this . Thank you very much @Jason for the knowledge . Kudos

Comment: Can you post your answer @Jason so that it will be helpful to others. I just solved my problem because of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following the suggestion of @Jason in the comment section I have solved my problem

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Hope this solves someone having thesame problem as mine.